# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.54 SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

We are trying to send mail through SMTP setup as below

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer, SMTPPort);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTPUserName, SMTPassword);
MailAddress mailAddress = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFromEmail))
   mailAddress = new MailAddress(sFromEmail);
else
   mailAddress = new MailAddress(SMTPEmailID);
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = mailAddress;
mailMessage.Subject = sEmailSubject;
foreach (string toAddress in sToEmail.Split(';'))
{
  if (toAddress.Trim() != string.Empty)
    mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
}
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.Body = sEmailBody;

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
logText.Add(Environment.NewLine);
logText.Add("Mail sent successfully at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
logCreation.createLogFileFromList(logText);
logText.Clear();
sErrorMessage = "Mail sent successfully";
```

but this end up with error

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.54 SMTP; Unable to
> relay recipient in non-accepted domain

any setup I am missing here..

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to sent to a mail where the domain is unkown over a public relay? that is like sending to tuser@aaahhhaaappp.de and using something like smtp.outlook.com which cannot resolve aaahhhaaappp.de

Comment: @Sascha my smtp server is XX.XX.XX.XXX and password..my email address is myname@mycompany.com

Comment: So if XX.XX.XX.XXX cannot resolve the recipients domain this might explain the error

Answer (score 0):

**First**
Email gateway is a SMTP server in charge of filter virus or spam. Email Gateway user maybe included spam list check this

**Second**
If you change your mail server ip address,your domain system may not have generalization dns in your exchange system.

**Third**
If you change your mail server ip address,your domain system may not have generalization your exchange system. You must be force generelization dns.
At this point can you check your project in running server
open powershell and edit your email info then run this query

```
send-mailmessage -to '<test@test.com>' -From '<admin@test.com>' -subject "TEST" -body "hi" -smtpServer mail.yourlocalsmtpdns.com
```

if you take this error change mail.yourlocalsmtpdns.com to your smtp ip address
if you not take error. You can think that your problem cause smtp domain address.

Fast solution,
you can connect to smtp with smtp ip address to your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your client's (application server's) ip address is added to the SMTP Server receive connector otherwise it will not work
2. Edit your code to look like this

> ```
> SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer, SMTPPort);
> smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
> smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
> smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTPUserName, SMTPassword);
> smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
> MailAddress mailAddress = null;
> if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFromEmail))
>    mailAddress = new MailAddress(sFromEmail);
> else
>    mailAddress = new MailAddress(SMTPEmailID);
> MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
> mailMessage.From = mailAddress;
> mailMessage.Subject = sEmailSubject;
> foreach (string toAddress in sToEmail.Split(';'))
> {
>   if (toAddress.Trim() != string.Empty)
>     mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
> }
> mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
> mailMessage.Body = sEmailBody;
>
> smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
> logText.Add(Environment.NewLine);
> logText.Add("Mail sent successfully at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
> logCreation.createLogFileFromList(logText);
> logText.Clear();
> sErrorMessage = "Mail sent successfully";
> ```

3. Configuring an anonymous SMTP relay connector (this is not advisable). You can find out more about it here https://practical365.com/exchange-2016-smtp-relay-connector/